# Jquery modal box to open a link and be degradable

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo

I had a couple of questions in regards to a modal box plugin which I have found online. The code for my link is below:

```
<li><a href="#" id="country_link"><span id="label">Country: </span><span id="strong">United Kingdom</span></a>
```

This is what I want to use to trigger the opening of the modal box but I can't work out how I point the link to the modal box, importantly so that if javascript is still disabled, it will still link to another page. I think e prevent default is what I need but I am not sure.

```
// Modal Box
// Version 0.1

(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        leanModal: function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                top: 100,
                overlay: 0.5,
                closeButton: null
            }
            var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
            $("body").append(overlay);
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var o = options;
                $(this).click(function (e) {
                    var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");
                    $("#lean_overlay").click(function () {
                        close_modal(modal_id);
                    });
                    $(o.closeButton).click(function () {
                        close_modal(modal_id);
                    });
                    var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();
                    var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();
                    $('#lean_overlay').css({
                        'display': 'block',
                        opacity: 0
                    });
                    $('#lean_overlay').fadeTo(200, o.overlay);
                    $(modal_id).css({
                        'display': 'block',
                            'position': 'fixed',
                            'opacity': 0,
                            'z-index': 11000,
                            'left': 50 + '%',
                            'margin-left': -(modal_width / 2) + "px",
                            'top': o.top + "px"
                    });
                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });

            function close_modal(modal_id) {
                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
                $(modal_id).css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain to you how does it work.

You need two parts. Element, that will trigger modal box and element that is modal box.

This two parts are connected with href, as you understood well. Now the tricky part is, that first character in href has to be "#". Also modalbox id has to be same as href, except "#" character. Here is the code:

```
<a href="#my-first-modal-box" id="country_link">
  <span id="label">Country: </span><span id="strong">United Kingdom</span>
</a>

<div id="my-first-modal-box"> This is what appears in modal box </div>
```

Now javascript/jQuery code. You will simple call function on a href:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#country_link").leanModal();

});
```

Now after click on link, modal box will appear. Because link start with #, it doesnt call new page or page reload ;) (yes it is tricky part). Also I suggest to you to put this modal box in your html code directly under the link. So if javascript is turned off, then modal box is just simple div under the link and it is always visible. So your javascript will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#my-first-modal-box").hide(); // this will hide modal box with javascript. 
                                   // It appears only if you click on link and it 
                                   // is visible if javascript is turned off

  // you can add some options, like close buttons
  var myCloseButton = $("<div class=\"close-button\"></div>"); 

  // you append close button only if it is with javascript
  myCloseButton.appendTo("#my-first-modal-box"); 

  $("#country_link").leanModal({ closeButton : myCloseButton });

});
```